# Apollo Server: How to disregard/bypass caching if Redis connection is lost during run time

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

Is there any way to disable caching during run time if ever the Redis server suddenly fails, for example, a graphic query has been carried out fine in the first request and assuming the response is cached, but suddenly the redis server crashed for some reason and this causes the succeeding request to stuck in loading until such time it times out.